# Add Facebook like button iOS SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-like

I'm trying to add the like button in my iOS Swift app, following  [the Facebook tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios/like-button)

I use Pods and a Bridging Header file to add the FB framework:

```
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 4.11'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
```

Bridging_Header.h

```
#ifndef isam_Bridging_Header_h
#define isam_Bridging_Header_h

#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit.h>
#endif
```

I updated the plist with the App Facebook ID

[image]

Then, in my viewDidLoad I added:

```
 let likeButton:FBSDKLikeControl = FBSDKLikeControl()
 likeButton.objectID = "https://www.facebook.com/cestunmac/"
 likeButton.frame = mailButton.frame
 likeButton.likeControlStyle = .BoxCount
 self.addSubview(likeButton)
```

The like button is displayed but when I press on it, nothing happens.
I don't understand what I miss

EDIT 1

AppDelegate.swift

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    //Do stuff
    //...


    FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    return true
}


func application(application: UIApplication,openURL url: NSURL,sourceApplication: String?,annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application,openURL: url,sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)    
}


func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {

    //Do stuff 
    //...

    FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
}
```

MyViewController.swift

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    //Do stuff 
    //...

    let likeButton:FBSDKLikeControl = FBSDKLikeControl()
    likeButton.objectID = "https://www.facebook.com/cestunmac/"
    likeButton.likeControlStyle = .BoxCount
    self.shareAndCommentView.addSubview(likeButton) 
}
```

Comment: Have integrate login button as well or not?

Comment: Not, because nothing happens when I click on the button

Comment: does the login view pop up when you click on it?

Comment: And are you sure the press is registered? Just create a simple button to confirm that

Comment: No nothings happens, I did not even the login view. I have others buttons in the view which work perfectly. When I press the button I just see the press effect on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the info.plist :

- it's **FacebookAppID** (and not FacebookAppId)
- remove the "fb" in the FacebookAppID string (set the string just with the numbers)

To debug my Facebook like button, I had to add a login Facebook button in my view controller to have the Facebook logs in the console.

Adding:

```
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>
```

and using:

```
let loginButton:FBSDKLoginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
loginButton.center = self.view.center
self.view.addSubview(loginButton)
```

Then the logs with my mistakes appeared.

After correcting them, I removed the Facebook login button, and the like button works well!